# How to read from a file and send it to a constructor in Java

Tags: java, constructor, io, bufferedreader

I have a code that reads an id block of three lines from a text file, I want to split those lines in Strings and an int, and pass this to a constructor from another class.
Right now, this class asks for an id number and prints everything below the # sign, down to and including the third line of each id block. I want those three lines in each id to be parsed as 'name', 'age' and 'job' to an Employee class, in order to create an object of the id, like this: Employee("Richard Smith",22,"Electric engineer"). There will always be three lines in the file for an id, so how can I "find" those lines and split them into Strings and an int?

```
#1000
Richard Smith
22
Electric engineer

#1001
Elliot Smith
23
Physicist



public class RdB
{
    String b; //file name

    RdB(String ename) {
        b = ename;
    }

    //info about an employee
    boolean showE (String id) {
        int ch;
        String code, info;

        //open the file with the info
        try (BufferedReader showERdr = 
            new BufferedReader (new FileReader(b)))
        {
            do {
                //read characters until a '#' is found
                ch = showERdr.read();

                //check
                if(ch == '#') {
                    code = showERdr.readLine();
                    if(id.compareTo(code) == 0) { //found employee
                        do {
                            info = showERdr.readLine();
                            if(info != null) {
                                System.out.println(info);
                            }
                        } while(((info != null) &&
                            (info.compareTo("") != 0)));
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            } while(ch != -1);
        }
        catch(IOException exc) {
            System.out.println("File error!");
            return false;
        }
        return false; //employee not found
    }

    //Access a registered employee
    String getE() {
        String id = "";

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Enter id number: ");
        try{
            id = br.readLine();
        }
        catch(IOException exc) {
            System.out.println("Access error");
        }
        return id;
    }
}
```

Edit:
Employee class

```
class Employee {
private String name, job;
private int age;

    public Employee (String name, int age, String job) {
       this.name = name;
       this.age = age;
       this.job = job;
    }

    public String getName () {
       return name;
    }

    public int getAge () {
       return age;
   }

    public String getJob () {
       return job;
  }

}
```

Comment: how about starting by writing the `Employee` class

Comment: @ScaryWombat 'class Employee {
private String name, job;
private int age;

 public Employee (String name, int age, String job) {
 this.name = name;
 this.age = age;
 this.job = job;
    }

 public String getName () {
 return name;
    }
 
 public int getAge () {
 return age;
   }

 public String getJob () {
 return job;
  }
 

}'

Comment: better to update the question rather than add this as a comment I thinks

Comment: The file format is a contract?? I mean, the three lines of a Employee block are always in the order: name, age, job??

Comment: @CarlitosWay It's a plain text file. It's just a software I'm writing for practicing oop AND I/O at the same time. If it were a professional software I think I would use an Oracle db, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an `ArrayList` to save what you read from the file and process it later. Since you are certain about the features of your saved file that it will always contain 3 lines before the line which contains ID, here is the working code I wrote to solve your problem. You can see the output wrapped between `( )`
Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Emp{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    List data = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("PeopleData.txt"));
    String str;
    while((str = reader.readLine()) != null){
 //         System.out.println(str);
        data.add(str);
    }
    for(int i= 0; i< data.size(); i ++){
                i++;
                System.out.println("(");
                System.out.println(data.get(i));
                String name = (String) data.get(i);
                i++;
                System.out.println(data.get(i));
                int age = Integer.valueOf((String) data.get(i));
                i++;
                System.out.println(data.get(i));
                String job = (String) data.get(i);
                i++;
                System.out.println(")");
                //new Employee(name, age, job);
            }
}
}
```

Comment: Where do I pass the variables to the Employee constructor?

Comment: The comment in the end @Rafa_Asp1

Comment: But if I write Employee.getName(); below (outside the for) I get "non-static method getName() cannot be referenced from a static context".

Comment: You said you wanted to create an object of the employee so you have to do this: 'Employee e = new Employee(name, age, job); e.getName();'

Comment: @Rafa_Asp1 Was it helpful?